# Serializing a private struct - Can it be done?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a public class that contains a private struct. The struct contains properties (mostly string) that I want to serialize. When I attempt to serialize the struct and stream it to disk, using XmlSerializer, I get an error saying only public types can be serialized. I don't need, and don't want, this struct to be public. Is there a way I can serialize it and keep it private?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) then you should be able to control exactly what and how the data is serialized.
If you look at the example in the provided link, they serialize a private string.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I could make this work, but it makes the job a lot more difficult than it should be IMO.

Comment: @Randy I don't think there is another way around it. I have run into this in the past and was very frustrated by it. If you use the XML serializer it will only serialize public data members unless you implement the IXmlSerializable interface (not ISerializable which is what got me in the past, I was unable to recover private data)

Comment: The error is that only public *types* can be serialized, not public *members*.  Just pointing this out.

Comment: @yoda from my reading of the XmlSerializer documentation, it explicitly only serializes public members: "During XML serialization, only the public properties and fields of an object are serialized." - from [Xml Serialization in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx). I would assume from that that private types wouldn't serialize either, but if you do the serialization yourself (via the interface) you should be able to serialize anything you want.